# Displaying a different language content from a properties file in Android

Tags: android

I am building an Android app where some data are stored in a properties file. It is in English and Malayalam language. It is read into a string array. I am able to do that.

But when I try to display it in Android Malayalam language content is not displaying properly. My properties file is like

```
ENG=Rotation,Longitude,Revolution
MAL="ഭ്രമണം","രേഖാംശം","വിപ്ലവം"
```

I am reading it like below

```
Properties properties = new Properties();;
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open("wordlist.properties");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] descrArray = properties.getProperty("ENG").split(",");
        String[] titleArray = properties.getProperty("MAL").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to support character encoding UTF-8 inorder to display it correctly try this:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream =  assetManager.open("wordlist.properties");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        properties.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] descrArray = properties.getProperty("ENG").split(",");
    String[] titleArray = properties.getProperty("MAL").split(",");
```